# Log4j Default Close Operation Log

Tags: java, swing, jframe, log4j

How to get an exit application log of jFrame in log4j when i have set

`setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `ShutdownHook` to the `main()` method. Then you can do whatever you want inside the hook, including logging before the application closes.

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29